# insert csv file into snowflake as variant not working

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to copy csv data into snowflake table with only one column(variant). When I run copy into statement, my variant column is only displaying data from first column. I'm not sure what the problem is. Please help.

Create or replace table name(
RAW variant )

COPY INTO db_name.table_name
FROM (SELECT s.$1::VARIANT FROM @stage_name.csv s);

Comment: Can you share a sample of your CSV file (anonymized if required)? Normally CSV would be loaded into a typed table with multiple columns. A table with a single variant column is typically used for semistructured data from JSON and JSON containing file types.

Comment: thank you this helps, we are ingesting csv data(structured obviously) so now I am think variant is not best way to go. I think our thought was to use variant to capture all the metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your .csv file consists of multiple, valid JSON, try using a file format of type JSON instead of .csv. See https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html.
Alternatively, use PARSE_JSON in your SELECT.